# VBA Excel Can't execute code in break mode?

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting this error in my code:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim start As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim amount As Integer
    amount = 0
    Dim answer As Range
    Set answer = Range("K22:K28")

    For k = Range("K22").Row To Range("K28").Row
        For j = Range("B11").Row To Range("B371").Row Step 7
             amount = amount + j
        Next
        k = amount
        amount = 0
    Next
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do in this code is to loop through every 7 instances of the B column, get their value and sum them together, store the sum at the cells starting K22 and start the loop again from the next B cell following, in this case B12, with B12's sum to be stored in K23 and so forth. What am I doing wrong here? Please let me know, any pointers to the right direction would be great.

I'm trying to make a button for this, when clicking the button will run through my program and start calculating and displaying.

Comment: You have no Next in either of your For loops. I haven't analysed if your code will work, but if you put a Next statements directly above the End Sub and then another Next directly above "amount = 0" then your syntax for the loops should be right.

Comment: You have to use the keyword `Set` to assign a range to a range variable also just use `For k = 22 to 28` when you already know the row. Same goes for `j` and `k` is an integer not a range variable so just use `k = amount`.

Comment: Hmm, changed what Davy C told me to and most of what newguy told me too, but I was a little lost on newguy's explaination, probs just me being dumb... I'm still getting the same errors though :/ not sure what's still going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I believe you were writing.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim b As Long, k As Long
    Dim amount As Double

    For k = 22 To 28
        For b = 11 + (k - 22) To 371 + (k - 22) Step 7
             amount = amount + Range("B" & b)
        Next b
        Range("K" & k) = amount
        amount = 0
    Next k
End Sub
```

After changing it in the VBE use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet.

Comment: Wow I think this is correct! I've gotta test it first, but at least from the values it's generated for me it should be correct! Thank you very much!